# Full width gallery with an image in the center

Tags: html, css

I have to create a gallery with "endless" width, each slide is `940px` wide, the website center is simple `width:940px;margin: 0 auto 0;` how can i force the **current** image to be exactly at the center of the website ?

here is my attempts:

1

```
  #gallery {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

2

```
  #gallery {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

Note that i can solve this layout issue with javascript, i am looking for a solution with
**pure** css.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us a live sample, an image can simply be aligned center with `text-align: center;` in parent tag unless there are other styles on it! So if it's not working, you should provide complete code or live sample ...

Comment: @Night2 even if all images are `940px` ?

Comment: As long as it's like this: `<div style="text-align: center;"><img /></div>`, If your image is bigger than screen, then it will cause scroll bars ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help - the following CSS will place a div in the center/middle (horizontally and vertically) rather than just centered horizontally as with align:center.

http://jsfiddle.net/fSNJR/

```
#centerdiv { 
position:absolute; 
top:50%; 
left:50%; 
width:940px; 
height:300px; 
margin-top:-150px; /* Half your height */
margin-left:-470px; /* Half your width */
background:#333; }
```